# Support Limit with Nhibernate and Sybase

Tags: nhibernate, limit, sybase, linq-to-nhibernate

The Nhibernate dialect for sybase ase 15 does not currently supports limit ("select top..."). Is there a way to make it work or activate it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to implement any Sybases ASE 15 specifics in the corresponding dialect. You can inherit from the dialect included with NHibernate and add what you need, or update the NHibernate code directly and rebuild. The latter scenario has the benefit that you can submit the changes to be included in NHibernate core.